# Принять произвольное количество строк и вывести их в обратном порядке, не используя списки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите решить задачу. Мы принимаем на ввод произвольное число строк (признак окончания ­— пустая строка) и вывести их в обратном порядке, НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЯ СПИСКИ.

Пример:

```
Привет
Как дела
Понятно
```

Вывод:

```
Понятно
Как дела
Привет
```

Как сделать это не использую списки вообще?

Comment: Ну, используя например строку) Прочитать все данные в одну строку, найти два символа переноса подряд и дальше выполнять поиск по строке влево, печатая срез строки после нахождения очередного символа переноса

Comment: Каждая строка начинается с большой буквы, и остальные буквы в строке маленькие?

Comment: скорее тут имелась ввиду рекурсия)

Comment: @eri посмотрите историю редактирования вопроса, и станет понятно, чем был вызван мой вопрос

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Рекурсия

```
>>> def rreverse():
...     a = input()
...     if a:
...         rreverse()
...         print(a)
... 
>>> rreverse()
Привет
Как дела
Понятно
Понятно
Как дела
Привет
>>>
```

Comment: Красиво, элегантно!

Comment: Спасибо за вашу помощь))

Answer (score 2):

Используйте строку для накопления

```py
temp = "\0"
s = ""
while temp != "":
  temp = input()
  s = temp + '\n' + s # сразу записываем в обратном порядке. Введено позже - записано раньше

print(s.strip())
```

Результат

```
Каждый охотник
Желает
Знать где
Сидит
Фазан

Фазан
Сидит
Знать где
Желает
Каждый охотник
```

Comment: начинать строку с "\0" плохая идея. Лучше оставить один инпут за пределами while - и стрип не понадобится и вопросов у проверяющего меньше

Comment: @eri `strip()` убирает не только нуль-символ в конце строки, но и перенос в начале строки, который добавляется, когда вводится пустая строка

Comment: Неимоверно благодарен))